# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document' to 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult'.

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following webapi

```
 public class TenantController : ApiController
    {
        private static DocumentClient client;

        public TenantController()
        {
            client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["endpoint"]), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authKey"]);
        }

        public async Task<List<Tenant>> GetTenants()
        {
            return await  DocumentDBRepository<List<Tenant>>.GetItemsAsync(d => d. != null);
        }

        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetTenant(string id) 
        {
            Tenant tenant= await DocumentDBRepository<Tenant>.GetItemAsync(id);

            if (tenant == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(tenant);
        }

        public async Task<IHttpActionResult>  PutTenant(string id, Tenant tenant)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            if (id != tenant.TenantId)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            await DocumentDBRepository<Tenant>.CreateItemAsync(tenant);

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent); 
        }

        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostTenant(string id, Tenant tenant)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            return await DocumentDBRepository<Tenant>.UpdateItemAsync(id, tenant);
        }

        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteTenant(string id)
        {
            await DocumentDBRepository<Tenant>.DeleteItemAsync(id);
            return Ok(id);
        }
    }
```

But I am having issues with the post tenant method

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document' to
>   'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult'.

Yes I know how a cast works, but I wonder if I am doing something incorrectly here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't told us which line the error occurs on but my guess would be here

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostTenant(string id, Tenant tenant)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        /// Error is here
        return await DocumentDBRepository<Tenant>.UpdateItemAsync(id, tenant);
    }
```

The problem is that it's returning the document directly. It probably should be

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostTenant(string id, Tenant tenant)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var result = await DocumentDBRepository<Tenant>.UpdateItemAsync(id, tenant);

        return Ok(result);
    }
```

Which returns the correct type.

Comment: yeah, sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

Your returning the awaited result of 
await DocumentDBRepository.UpdateItemAsync(id, tenant); as a IHttpActionResult.

try

```
var result = await DocumentDBRepository<Tenant>.UpdateItemAsync(id, tenant);
return Ok(result);
```